# slicing and plotting 3D array with Python

Tags: python, plot, slice

i am rather new in python and before was a MATLAB user. I am sorry if my question is to obvious. 
I have a huge 47MB file that contains 3D array (351:467:300). That is 300 images from a camera. I want to re-plot them as a kind of animation. Basically, just slice and plot all 300 images. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as c
datafile = c.loadmat('data.mat') # loading data
img = datafile['img'] # extracting the (351:467:300) array 
imgShape = np.shape(img) 
for i in range(0,imgShape(2)):
    plt.imshow(img[:,:,i])
    time.sleep(0.3)
    plt.draw()

print('Done!')
```

the problem is: when  it comes to imshow the figure window is black and NOT RESPONDING until it finishes the loop, so i can't see anything. How to solve this? How to force it to update "on stream" ?

And the plotting is veeeryyy slow compared to matlab (not because of time.sleep :) i tried without :) ) loop runs really slowly. I am using Spyder, is that a reason ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: :Try to use first plt.draw() and then time.sleep(0.3).Does it work?

Comment: nope %) it does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the following corrections:**
you need to make it interactive.

```
import numpy as np
#import time
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as c
import pylab as pl                     #added 

datafile = c.loadmat('data.mat') # loading data
img = datafile['img'] # extracting the (351:467:300) array 
imgShape = np.shape(img) 
pl.ion()                               #added 
for i in range(imgShape(2)):           #no need for 0
    pl.cla()                           #added
    pl.imshow(img[:,:,i])
#    time.sleep(0.3) 
    pl.draw()
    pl.pause(0.3)                      #added   
pl.ioff()                              #added
print('Done!')
```

Comment: Thanks ! that works ! I have to make myself more familiar with packages !

Comment: is it possible to save the resulting "animation" as a "movie file" ?

Comment: @Vladde A very simple and general solution for saving animation is to save each run as image file (e.g., add `pl.savefig('%05d.png'%i)` after `pl.draw()`) and then to use many available tools such as [`Photoscape`](http://www.photoscape.org/ps/main/index.php) to generate animations as `GIF` or `AVI` etc formats.